# Get random questions in a quizgame django API

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to recreate game of hacks because there isnt an API to create my own questions , and implement on external site , however I am using django with restful framework for this task. (I am not sure , if this is the right to achieve this). I will do this via server because I dont want people change js and bypass the stuff or even disable js and stop time , and continue with the same question

apiview.py

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def questions_view(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        questions = Question.objects.all()
        serializer = QuestionListPageSerializer(questions, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = QuestionListPageSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            question = serializer.save()
            return Response(QuestionListPageSerializer(question).data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

serializers

```
class QuestionListPageSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    question_text = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = serializers.DateTimeField()
    was_published_recently = serializers.BooleanField(read_only=True) # Serializer is smart enough to understand that was_published_recently is a method on Question
    code = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Question.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        for key, value in validated_data.items():
            setattr(instance, key, value)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

question list my app

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: POST, OPTIONS, GET
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "question_text": "helllo",
        "pub_date": "2020-01-15T02:30:40Z",
        "was_published_recently": false,
        "code": "int main (int argc, char *argv[])\r\n{\r\n\tchar *val = argv[argc -1];\r\n\tsystem(val);\r\n\treturn(0);\r\n}"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "question_text": "What is the meaning of life?",
        "pub_date": "2020-01-15T02:30:40Z",
        "was_published_recently": false,
        "code": "SOME STRING"
    }
]
```

question with answer  my app

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: PATCH, OPTIONS, DELETE, GET
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "id": 1,
    "question_text": "helllo",
    "pub_date": "2020-01-15T02:30:40Z",
    "was_published_recently": false,
    "code": "int main (int argc, char *argv[])\r\n{\r\n\tchar *val = argv[argc -1];\r\n\tsystem(val);\r\n\treturn(0);\r\n}",
    "choices": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "choice_text": "11111"
        }
    ]
}
```

#### game of hacks external app

```
{
  "_id": "53fb4014e5d4d40400c7fa4f",
  "answers": [
    "LDAP Injection",
    "CGI Reflected XSS",
    "Connection String Injection",
    "Reflected XSS"
  ],
  "batch_score": 39.89902034664657,
  "checkmarx": true,
  "from": "Gilad",
  "language": "PHP",
  "level": "1",
  "question": "What vulnerability the following code contains?",
  "snippets": [
    {
      "code": "<?php\n$dn = $_GET['host'];\n$filter=\"(|(sn=$person*)(givenname=$person*))\";\n$justthese = array(\"ou\", \"sn\", \"givenname\", \"mail\");\n$sr=ldap_search($ds, $dn, $dn, $justthese);\n$info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr);\necho $info[\"count\"].\" entries returned\n\";?>"
    }
  ],
  "tip": ""
}
```

example

http://www.gameofhacks.com/api/answer

answer

```
{quest: true, score: 5700}
quest: true
score: 5700
```

http://www.gameofhacks.com/api/question # make random instead of `api/poll/question/{id}` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use python `random` library in your view:

```py
from random import randint

def random_question(request):
    i = randint(0, Question.objects.count() - 1)
    question = Question.objects.all()[i]  # get question at random position
    ....
```

Comment: Use "Question.objects.get(id=i)" instead of "Question.objects.all()[i]".

Comment: @wfehr if you delete an instance of Question, that ID will be missing from the database, and if you try to access that ID you will get an exception. With my answer you don't need to worry about exceptions.

Comment: Right, didn't think of that.